# NestJS global auth global guard clashing with RabbitMQ subscriber

Tags: node.js, graphql, rabbitmq, nestjs, passport.js

I'm using `@golevelup/nestjs-rabbitmq` to handle RabbitMQ messages from a queue, the global guard is intercepting the requests from the queue. Is there any way to prevent the global guard to get these requests?

Auth guard

```
@Injectable()
export default class GqlAuthGuard extends AuthGuard(AuthStrategy.Jwt) {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {
    super();
  }

  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);

    return ctx.getContext();
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>(IS_PUBLIC_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);

    if (isPublic) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.canActivate(context);
  }
}
```

RabbitMQ Subscriber

```
@SubscribeToEvent({
    queue: Topic.SendSurvey,
  })
  async handler({ surveyId, schedulingEventId }: HandlerParams) {
    this.logger.info('Handling message', surveyId, schedulingEventId);

    this.surveysService.dispatch(surveyId, schedulingEventId);
  }
```

The error I'm getting

```
[22-03-24 02:52:31] [error] [app] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'req') {"0":"MotivatoExceptionsHandler"}
[22-03-24 02:52:31] [error] [app] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'req') {"0":"MotivatoExceptionsHandler"}
[22-03-24 02:52:31] [error] [app] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'req') {"0":"MotivatoExceptionsHandler"}
[22-03-24 02:52:31] [error] [app] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'req') {"0":"MotivatoExceptionsHandler"}
```

I tried changing the `getRequest` but it didn't work

Comment: That `AuthGuard()` is using `passport` under the hood which is an `HTTP` middleware (specifically for Express). RabbitMQ is a completely different protocol with different context properties. If you plan to use it with this, you'd need to create your own mapper for passport to work, otherwise just skip the guard if `context.getType() === 'rpc'`

Answer (score 0):

```
async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
  const type = context.getType<'rmq'>()
  if (type === 'rmq') {
    return true
  }
  ...
}
```

It works when adding in this way

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.